My PhD supervisor was not satisfied with the authorship of the paper from my dissertation
I graduated from an R1 university with a major that could be described as either social science or business. TBH, my committee chair provided significant spiritual support throughout the process, but had very little direct involvement in my dissertation. Another professor on my committee was incredibly helpful, even after I graduated. She assisted me in reorganizing the structure of my dissertation to convert it into journal papers and also proofread the drafts. So I listed her as second author and my supervisor as third. My supervisor immediately emailed me asking why she was not listed as the second author. I was hurt by her response, as she had always emphasized the importance of fairness in authorship. I’ve consistently listed her as a co-author for the various projects I’ve consulted with her on, even though, in most cases, she only provided time to discuss without being involved in the entire process. More importantly, neither professor is in competition with the other.
I know that I didn’t communicate well with her about this. The issue is that she has always been slow in her responses. I used to wait outside her office as early as 8 a.m. on the days she taught undergraduate courses, hoping for a chance to speak with her. But I am thousands miles from there now. I sent her my paper in May but did not receive any feedback by November. When I followed up with Whatsapp, she always said she was still working on it next week, next week and next week.  This led me to make the decision to submit the paper without further consultation. I am in a tenure process, and there is no way for me to wait a year feedback, and most of time, the feedback is surface. I dont know. ... Well, she is nice in teaching and talking, but not really in projects. TBH, I didnot have any successful publication with her. I dont know, I respect her. Should I give up my dissertation, withdrawl the paper and just move on to new projects？or Just feel sad.

Was the paper already accepted and published? Or is it still under revision?

On a separate note, here is how I have managed to deal with unresponsive collaborators. Send an email well in advance (at least a few weeks) detailing what your plan is for the project, where you clearly state that if you don't receive any objections by date X you will take it as a tacit agreement and move forward with your proposal. Add a reminder a few days prior to the deadline.

The issue that the responses deal with is not related to author order, it is related to submitting the manuscript without the full approval of all parties/authors. You are getting slightly confusing advice because there is a surface problem and a deeper underlying problem. Both are solvable with communications and you should not give up these publications.

Depending on what the supervisor chooses to do, you may be at some risk of having the paper withdrawn. You seem to have submitted it before you got agreement from all authors. They can, if they like, complain to the publisher that their permission was not given. That would probably require the publisher to withdraw the paper.
Honestly, I can't defend the submission prior to agreement. Sorry.
There is no reason to "give up your dissertation", but you might need to find a way to soothe the waters. And, I'd work on that prior to considering withdrawing the paper yourself. The "third" person (second author) probably has some things to contribute also.
There is also the question of field "norms". If the norm in your field is that supervisors are always second authors then you have additional risk.
But, IMO, this is a case of the danger of anything but alphabetical author order on published papers. Contributions an be listed, without implied ordering, in acknowledgement sections. And, yes, as a math/CS person, I'm an outlier on this.

It is common sense to include supervisor, but not have to be the second. Some ppl prefer as the last author. And some dont care. Indeed, according to the university tenure/rewarding or anything authorship order doesnot really matter in most cases. That is why I submit and feel suprise my supervisor care .I agree that it was my fault for submitting without full consent. However, not receiving proper recognition for others contributions makes me feel bad also. More importantly, the gap in contributions between the two  is significant.

@Resiture none of what you said matters. You submitted without full consent and without communicating with all authors involved. You mismanaged the process and created this situation. You are in the wrong.

... however, some of that may factor into the discussion you now need to have with your (former, I guess?) supervisor, @Resiture.  They did contribute to the situation by being so slow to act on the papers, but I recommend coming to that conversation with an apologetic and conciliatory attitude.  You might yet avoid burning any bridges.

@R1NaNo You may be correct, but you're not right. You are correct in that this is how the situation is viewed by the powers that be in academia. But you are not right in the sense that, reasonably speaking, the supervisor holds accountability for dawdling. If it were a legal right of first refusal that the supervisor had, then their actions would've forfeited their consent. I cant argue with Resiture making a mistake, but, in the bigger picture, they both contributed to this problem.

R1NaNo Following your suggestion, it seems the best course of action is to let go of my dissertation, which is what I plan to do next. However, I wonder—if you were working with a student who repeatedly pushes back deadlines month after month, at what point it touch your bottom line? When would you consider getting a new student invovled and moving this student from second author to third, or even removing this ppl from the project entirely? I tried to communicate, but not effectively. Your can warn your student, but do you think I can warn my supervisor?

@DavidS When you submit a paper for publication it requires approval of all authors, it is not what "the powers that be in academia" view it as. That does not mean their advisor is not without fault, but that doesn't matter, they have other consequences for their actions. They build a bad reputation, they have burnt bridges with former students, etc... They risk the student filing complaints with the chair/dean etc... However, that does not excuse the former student not following appropriate protocol for academic publishing.

@Resiture if I am paying that student (and in my line of research I am always paying the student) off a grant with deliverables, and they do not deliver then yes they will be moved off the project or their role lessened, because I am responsible for staffing it, and for seeing the work get done. There is no direct comparison with the student advisor relationship such as yours because unfortunately the power dynamic is not in your favor. However, if I play games with authorship I am committing academic misconduct and I open myself to punitive measures depending on the severity of my actions.

You need to talk to her directly! Apologise for submitting the paper without full agreement, and ask how she'd like to proceed. Tell her that you respect her, you realise you made a mistake because you were anxious about getting the paper submitted, that it won't happen again, and that you want to fix it. See what she says. Make it clear that you understand you were in the wrong, and don't be defensive or criticise her actions, even if they contributed to the current situation.

I think this course of action would be fine. At this point she should probably not ask you to withdraw the paper, unless she really disagrees with your work.
